# Как правильно написать: "экстракты растений" или "из растений"?

Tags: стилистика

Answer (score 1):

Если экстракт извлекается из всего растения, то экстракты растений. Если экстракт извлекается из частей растения (листьев, корней и т. д.), то употребляют оба варианта (но чаще без "из": экстракт плодов боярышника).

Answer (score 0):

экстракт растений